# Who should own a plugin repository in an open source project

Tags: git, github, open-source

I developed a free web app during 1 year on my own. Last week, I released it, and had great feedback from community.

Some programmers inside the community told me they already worked on something similar, and shared me a github repository where I can find their implementation.

Now, it is a great help, and there is thing in his implementation that I have still not develop which should be great help, and others than I have implemented that is not present in his plugin.

Now, how should we organize??? What I think is needed is merging my code with his plugin to make a more complete plugin.

Should we do it in his repository? Should I create my own public repository and tell him that I merged our plugins into a single one??? is it offensive not to use his repository???

My app is free but not open source, so it would be great that only core plugin could be open source. This is my first released app, so I don't really know how things should do...

The only thing I think is if my system is going to have a main core, I should "host" it.

Any advice???

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the license of the both the projects. You can't simply merge the other developer's project to your project without following the license terms. You can ask for his permission to merge the code to your project.

In my opinion you both must share a common repository for the project, GitHub allows you to add collaborators to the project. The project will be shown on your GitHub profile. You must update the readme, mentioning the ownership of the project. Another way to do this is using a GitHub organization for your project, so that the project is shown as the part of organization which you both are a part of.

Comment: there is no licence still. I already have the developper authorization to "just use it", but I want to do what is correct, value his work without losing my project control

Comment: I would suggest you to merge the code and add his name in the credits...